# MVC Ajax returning Partial view but it is not showing

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a page that asks for some details first and then returns a partial view in a div below it.

This is my Ajax (details are being taken and passed to the controller accordingly since I tested it):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Filter() {
    var startd = $('#startdt').val();
    var endd = $('#enddt').val();
    var itemname = $("#Products option:selected").val();

    var param = { StartD: startd, EndD: endd, ItemName: itemname };

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("FilterTransaction")',
        type: "POST",
        datatype: "html",
        UpdateTargetId: "divResult",
        data: param,
        error: function (xmlHttpRequest, errorText, thrownError) {
            alert(xmlHttpRequest + "|" + errorText + "|" + thrownError);
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $('divResult').html(result);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

This is the controller (methods and variables are processed all properly):

```
public PartialViewResult FilterTransaction(string StartD, string EndD, string ItemName)
    {
        try
        {
            int productid = new ProductService.ProductsServiceClient().GetProductID(ItemName);
            Product p = new ProductService.ProductsServiceClient().GetProduct(productid);
            ViewBag.ItemNo = productid;
            ViewBag.ItemName = p.Name;
            ViewBag.AmmountP = p.Price;
            int orderid = new OrderService.OrderServiceClient().GetOrderID(productid, User.Identity.Name);
            Order o = new OrderService.OrderServiceClient().GetOrder(orderid);
            ViewBag.DatePurchased = o.Date;
            ViewBag.WarrantyExpiryDate = o.Date.AddYears(2);

            DateTime fromd = Convert.ToDateTime(StartD);
            DateTime todate = Convert.ToDateTime(EndD);
            todate = todate.AddDays(1);

            List<PrintViewFD> printv = new List<PrintViewFD>();
            foreach (FaultDetail fs in new FaultService.FaultServiceClient().GetListOfFaultDetailsbetweenDATES(orderid, productid, fromd, todate))
            {
                PrintViewFD pvd = new PrintViewFD();
                pvd.date = fs.Date.ToString();
                pvd.details = fs.Details;
                pvd.faultid = fs.FaultID;
                FaultStatu fss = new FaultService.FaultServiceClient().GetStatus(fs.FaultStatusID);
                pvd.status = fss.Status;
                printv.Add(pvd);
            }

            ViewBag.FaultDetailsLIST = printv;
            return PartialView("_filtertransactions");
        }
        catch
        {
            return PartialView("_filtertransactions");
        }
    }
```

I debugged the function and it is entering both the controller method and the Partial View. The only problem is that the partial view is not being displayed in the view then. I think that it has to do with the ajax!

This is the div that should display it:

```
<div id="divResult">test</div>
```

Comment: `$('divResult')` -> `$('#divResult')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a mistake on your success method of the ajax call. You need to change divResult to "#divResult " and append 'data' to the html instead of 'success'
Try something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("FilterTransaction")',
    type: "POST",
    datatype: "html",
    UpdateTargetId: "divResult",
    data: param,
    error: function (xmlHttpRequest, errorText, thrownError) {
        alert(xmlHttpRequest + "|" + errorText + "|" + thrownError);
    },
    success: function (data) {
        $("#divResult").empty(); //In case you're going to refresh this multiple times
        $("#divResult").html(data);
    }
});
```